# node.js passing variables

Tags: database, node.js, variables

I am looking for some direction here from some seasoned node.js programmers. The biggest issue I am running into is passing around variables into separate modules. For example in my server.js I have the following:

```
var db = mongoose.createConnection('localhost','test');
```

Now I am not running my routes inside of the server.js file they are separated into there own files. So for a blog example it might be like this:

```
app.get('/blog/post/:id',function(req,res){
    //do something here
}
```

Now this is where the problem comes in. I do not want to have to setup a database connection in each of my routes and not to mention I would think that it would make a ton of connections. How do I handle this, is there a sample "REAL WORLD" application out there because I cannot seem to find anything about this and I know people have had to have this problem before. I know that node caches the modules but I cant imagine that it would cache the connection given it was in its own module. I created a config module that just holds the site config so requiring this where I need it is not a problem. I imagine there are other things that I am gonna wanna do this with so it would be best to figure this out now.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I do in my real world app.

I have a module named `redis` (that's the database I'm using). It contains the following code:

```
var store;

exports.store = store = redis.createClient(config.port, config.url);
```

So, I can directly access the client, if I need to. I almost never do that. The same module contains code like this:

```
exports.getData = function(dataID, callback){

    var key = DATA_STORE_PREFIX;

    try{
        store.hget(key, dataID, callback);
    } catch(err){
        callback(err);
    }
}
```

I use this by including the `redis` module in one or more route modules and calling it like this:

```
var db = require('redis');

db.getData('someData', function(err, result){
    console.log(result); // real world code goes here!
});
```

The node module system takes care of the rest.

Comment: So my only question about this is does this create a new connection everytime? I actually started doing this already but i want to be sure it doesnt.

Comment: It seems to reuse an existing connection, if it has one. If connections are automatically dropped when not used then it will reconnect.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it is to add the connection as a property of an object which will be available to all of the modules that need it. For example in my express app I have something like this in my main app file:

```
require('./config/database')(app);
```

and the `config/database` file looks like:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = function(app) {
  var database = app.get('env');
  var uri = database === 'production' ? 'something...' : 'localhost';
  return app.locals.db = mongoose.createConnection(uri, database);
};
```

Any modules that need a db connection can then access `app.locals.db` simply by exporting a function which takes `app` as an argument (just like above). Of course you'll need to modify this somewhat if you are using something other than express, but the idea remains the same.

Comment: Very creative solution but i think that kind of clouds the locals. This is definitely something useful though to pass in data to locals automatically

Comment: I think that's what `app.locals` is there for. I've taken this to an extreme in my current project by recursively auto-loading and assigning all major components of the application to properties of `app.locals` - e.g. all of my models are in `app.locals.models`. I like this pattern for two reasons: First, my modules work independently of the file structure, i.e. I don't have to write things like `require('../../models/user')` all over the place. Second, my shared libraries are available to the views - e.g. if I have an `app.locals.lib.urlFor`, I can use it in a view as `lib.urlFor`.

Comment: Yeah like i said i think it has its uses (especially for config or utilities) but the db i like being able to just require. Thanks though for the input u made a real valid point about the requires

Answer (score 1):

You are using express, I see. Just do:

```
app.set('db',  mongoose.createConnection('localhost','test'))
```

Then in any module constructor, make sure to pass the `app` variable, and you can use `app.get('db')` to get `db`to work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i think that the other solution fits much better. Then my modules can be more generic and it just seems cleaner.