# Access function in another module.export in a separate file

Tags: node.js, express

I have several javascript files that contain different parts of my node application.  They are required using the logic below.  I want to access a function in one file1.js from file2.js, but have had little success so far.  Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

app.js:  This is the file where I start my server and include all the express routes.

```
require(path_to_file+'/'+file_name)(app, mongoose_database, config_file);  //Require a bunch fo files here in a loop.
```

file1.js:  This is an example file that is required using the code above.

```
module.exports = function(app, db, conf){
  function test() {  //Some function in a file being exported.
    console.log("YAY");
  }
}
```

file2.js:  This is another file required using the code above.  I want to access a function in file1.js from within this file (file2.js).

```
module.exports = function(app, db, conf){
  function performTest() {  //Some function in a file being exported.
    test();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### file1.js

```
module.exports = function(app, db, conf){
  return function test() {
    console.log("YAY");
  }
}
```

Note you need to return the function.

#### file2.js

```
module.exports = function(app, db, conf){
  return function performTest() {
    var test = require('./file1')(app, db, conf);
    test();
  }
}
```

#### (some other file)

```
var test = require('./file2')(app, db, conf);
test();
```

or

```
require('./file2')(app, db, conf)();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  This method works if I have one function in a module.export, however if I have multiple functions in a file all in a module.export, how do I access those.  Is there a way to access the functions like this:  `var file1 = require('./file1')(app,db,conf);` and then `file1.test()`

Comment: Sure. Just have your exported function return an object with the property `test` whose value is a function. The discussion from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13151693/passing-arguments-to-require-when-loading-module) question may be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The function you have right now in file1 is scoped only to the function within the exports. Instead, you want to export an object with each function being a member of that object.

```
//file1.js
module.exports = {
    test: function () {
    }
};


//file2.js:
var file1 = require('./file1.js');
module.exports = {
    performTest: function () {
        file1.test();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey I tried playing around with this method, but I couldn't get it to work.  If I use your exact syntax I get an error point at the unexpected parenthesis `()` after the word `funtion`

Answer (score 0):

In [ECMAScript6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export) and above editions you can do it by `export` and `import` keywords.

First,implement and `export` an arrow function in a separate js file:

```
//file1.js
export const myFunc = () => {
    console.log("you are in myFunc now");
}
```

Then,`import` and call it in other files:

```
//otherfile.js

import { myFunc } from 'file1';

myFunc();
```

[If you want to more about Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: Should note that you need a compiler.  It won't just "work".