# pass init value in npm package

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Now I'm trying to write a first npm package but I have issue/question,
How can I pass value when developer required my package like that

```
const package = require('my-package')('hello A')
```

this is code for explain my idea

```
module.exports=(valueA){
 function : (ValueB)=>{
    console.log(valueA,ValueB)
 },
 middleware : (req,res,next)=>{
    console.log(req,valueA)
    return next();
 }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing arguments to require (when loading module)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13151693/passing-arguments-to-require-when-loading-module)

Comment: @Narm thanks, it's duplicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
module.exports=function (valueA) { 
     return {
      someMethod : function (ValueB) {
      console.log(valueA,ValueB)
      },
      middleware : function (req,res,next) {
       console.log(req,valueA)
       return next();
      } 
    }
}
```