# Pass command line argument from bin/www to app.js and then to module

Tags: node.js

I have looked at the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13151693/passing-arguments-to-require-when-loading-module) and while it is the right solution to passing an argument to a module, my requirement is to pass command like arguments from bin/www to app.js to a module.
This is a project created in WebStorm, which has bin/www as the startup script.

I have a traditional NodeJS project structure where the app starts at bin/www which call app.js and app.js has the router modules.

The startup script is bin/www which I cannot change and I want to pass an argument (path to a config file) to a router module.

What is the best way to achieve this without significantly changing the file structure?

app.js has the following structure:

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index')(path_config_file);
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
var app = express();


module.exports = app;
```

As I have shown I want to pass path_config_file to routes/index module, which will be passed as a command line argument.

I cannot start `app.js` because the project has existing CI/CD and I am not able to change that process.

I need to be able to pass the argument as `node bin/www path_config_file` and get it over to `app.js`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what you need is to read the `process.argv` var where those `command line` arguments are saved. Please look at the answers on the next post:

[How to pass command line arguments on node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351521/how-do-i-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-node-js-program?rq=1)