# Calling functions from a parameterized module.exports

Tags: javascript, node.js

Referencing [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13163075/4848310), I need to pass a parameter into `module.exports` of my `utils.js` file.

```
// utils.js
var module;
module.exports = function (name) {
    if (module) return module;

    module = {};

    module.sayHi = function () {
        return `Hi, ${name}`;
    };

    return module;
};
```

I'm a bit confused as to how to call `sayHi` after `require`ing `utils.js`.

```
// index.js
const utils = require("./utils")("Jim");    
utils.sayHi();
```

I'm getting `TypeError: utils.sayHi is not a function`. What's the right way to call `sayHi`?

Answer (score 0):

First you create a variable named `module`.

> ```
> var module;
> ```

This does **nothing** because you are doing this in the scope of the module, so that variable already exists.

---

Then you assign a function to `module.exports`.

In another module, you import that function and call it.

The first line of that function says:

> ```
> if (module) return module;
> ```

Is `module` a truthy value?

**Yes**. It is an object. If it wasn't, then assigning to `module.exports` would have throw an exception.

Consequently, you never overwrite `module = {};` or assign the `sayHi` function to it.

---

Now look at the answer you referenced:

> ```
> module.exports = function (app, db) {
>     var module = {};
> ```

It creates a *new* variable *in the scope of the function* so it doesn't conflict with the existing one.

Comment: The reason for `var module;` outside of the `module.exports` scope was to attempt caching of the module if referenced multiple times (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13151693/passing-arguments-to-require-when-loading-module/13163075#comment82835819_13163075). I could have a value in the module not worth recomputing multiple times. It's just that my current implementation doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @slider — As implied by the answer, you could just *use a different variable name* … but then it would cache the first name you passed to the `name` argument and you'd be stuck with it for subsequent invocations. If you want to cache sanely, you'd need to store the result from each `name` separately.

Comment: @slider But you don't want caching, if the exported function is called with different `name`s.

Comment: In this case, yes, `name` would be a bad parameter for something worth caching. But other values may indeed be worth caching.