# Passing arguments to require, when loading a router module with express router

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

This question is very related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13151693/passing-arguments-to-require-when-loading-module).

In my module I use following:

```
const express       = require('express'),
      router        = express.Router();
...
module.exports = router;
```

And I need access to objects in the app.js file. Something like `const routes = require(./routes/route.js)(data)`.

**What I tried**

- `module.exports = router(data)` But than `req`is undefined in the router object.
- Made an instance of `route`in app.js after requiring it. But this results in the same error message. (Like this:

```
var route = new Route();
route.data = data
```

- Pretty much the same like in the article I mentioned, but I'm not sure what I have to do with the router object. This does not work:

```
module.exports = router(data){
// all routes
};
```

**Additional information**

I normally use routes like this in app.js

```
const route = require('route.js');
app.use(route);
```

Comment: You need to do `module.exports = function (data) {/* code, not routes */}` or `module.exports = (data) => {/*again, NOT routes */}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if i understood your question, but if you want to pass data to a module that you require you could do something like this:

```
const express       = require('express'),
      router        = express.Router();

module.exports = function(data) {
   // do stuff with data
   router.get('/', (req, res) => res.send(data))

   return router;
}

// and then in app.js

const router = require('router.js')(/* pass data to router*/);

app.use(router)
```